# How to convert a value in GEKKO into a float

Tags: python, numeric, gekko

I am using GEKKO  to solve a system of non-linear differential equations. It is able to solve the equations and give me solutions, however the the solutions seem to be saved in some GEKKO object kind of format called "class 'gekko.gk_operators.GK_Value'".

Is there any way for me to convert this into a float? I need to manipulate these values to find to find their average.

Here is my code

```
from gekko import GEKKO
DELTA=1
OMEGA=0
GAMMA=1
J=3
m = GEKKO()
SZ1, SZ2, SZ3, SX1, SX2, SX3, SY1, SY2, SY3 = [m.Var(value=0) for i in range(9)]
m.Equations([4*J*(SX2*SY1-SX1*SY2)-GAMMA*(1+SZ1)+2*OMEGA*SY1==0,
         2*J*(-2*SX2*SY1+2*SX1*SY2+2*SX3*SY2-2*SX2*SY3)-GAMMA*(1+SZ2)+2*OMEGA*SY2==0,
         2*J*(-2*SX3*SY2+2*SX2*SY3)-GAMMA*(1+SZ3)+2*OMEGA*SY3==0,
         J*SY2*SZ1-0.5*GAMMA*SX1-DELTA*SY1==0,
         2*J*SY1*SZ2-2*J*SY3*SZ2-0.5*GAMMA*SX2-DELTA*SY2==0,
         J*SY2*SZ3-0.5*GAMMA*SX3-DELTA*SY3==0,
         J*SX2*SZ1+0.5*GAMMA*SY1-DELTA*SX1+2*OMEGA*SZ1==0,
         2*J*SX1*SZ2-2*J*SX3*SZ2+0.5*GAMMA*SY2-DELTA*SX2+2*OMEGA*SZ2==0,
         J*SX2*SZ3+0.5*GAMMA*SY3-DELTA*SX3+2*OMEGA*SZ3==0])
m.solve(disp=True)
print([SZ1.value, SZ2.value, SZ3.value])    
ans=(SZ1.value+SZ2.value+SZ3.value)/3
print(ans)
```

Is there any was for me to convert SZ1, SZ2 and SZ3 into float values?

Comment: Gekko is built for standard optimization and also for dynamic (time-varying) optimization. The values are stored as arrays so you can access the floating point numbers with `SZ1.value[0]`. If it were a dynamic problem then the array would be equal to the length of your time definition with `len(m.time)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unpacking the list will do.

`ans=(SZ1.value[0]+SZ2.value[0]+SZ3.value[0])/3`